# Behaviour of functions in weighted sobolev spaces

Tags: measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

If $f$ and $Df$ are in $L^2(\mathbb{R}, e^{u^2} dx)$, can we say $f(u)e^{\frac{u^2}{2}}$ is bounded.
Here $Df$ distributional derivatie of $f$.
 That is, If $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert f(u) \rvert^2 e^{u^2}du < \infty$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert Df(u) \rvert^2 e^{u^2}du < \infty$.
1) Can we say $f(u)e^{\frac{u^2}{2}}$ is bounded?
2) can we say $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \lvert f(x) p(x) \rvert = 0$ for
every real polynomial?

Comment: A trivial counterexample for 1), which I assume you didn't actually intend to include:  let $f(n)=1$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, zero otherwise.  You presumably meant only bounded a.e. (finite $L^\infty$ norm) -- or not?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. By sobolev embedding theorem that resulting function f becomes continuous. So, bounded a.e and bounded both are same for continuous functions.